# Not able to convert string value to float in C# according to IEEE 754

Tags: c#, string, floating-point, ieee-754

Well I have a string value of **"1.36383E+37"** and I want convert in float type according to IEEE 754. See the code below:

```
        try
        {
            return float.Parse(val, NumberStyles.Float | NumberStyles.AllowThousands, cultureInfo);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
        }
```

It is not able to parse the value and throwing me an exception of 
**"Value was either too large or too small for a Single"**

Any help would be thankful.

Comment: Just curious, since it looks like you need absolute precision why not use decimal?.

Comment: @NightOwl888 The upper limit in finite IEEE 754 32-bit binary floating point is about 3.4e38, over 20 times the value I think the OP intends.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I suspect you are using a `cultureInfo` for a culture that uses `.` as a thousands separator. For example, `CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("it")` (Italian) results with the error you describe for that data, as do several others. You should use a culture that matches the way the number is written. For machine-produced strings, `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture` would be the best option.

Comment: @AkhilNair I have checked the latest version of the question. It does not show the value of `cultureInfo`. "." not being the decimal point would explain the behavior you are seeing.

Comment: @AkhilNair The edit made no difference. 3E38 is in the float range. 136383E+37 is out of range.

Comment: @PatriciaShanahan the edit did make a difference because there were spaces prior to the edit, so it would fail with invariant culture too (albeit with a different message).